# Check process is a martingale

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

I have such stochastic process with which I struggle all day, finally I found 2 mistakes, however answer is still unsatisfying. $$X_t = atW_t^2 - \int_0^t(W_s^2+s)ds,$$
I need to check if it is a martingale. 
I simply write Ito formula for $X_t(t,W_t,S_t)$, where I denote by $S_t = \int_0^tW_s^2ds$.
So I apply it, and get:
$$dX_t=  (aW_t^2 - t -W_t^2 +at )dt + 2atW_tdW_t,$$
I pick function $f_t$, which should be equal to zero if the process is a martingale.
$$aW_t^2 - t -W_t^2 +at  = 0,$$
so my $a$ is $a = 1$.

**BUT!**
I have decided to check it substituting the $a$ into the $X_t$ and calculating expectation(using martingale property ($\mathbb{E}(X_t \mid \mathcal{F_s}) = X_s$), and I get problems.
As far as I understand I should get:
$$\mathbb{E} \left(tW_t^2- \int_0^t(W_s^2+s)ds  \mid \mathcal{F_s} \right) = sW_s^2 - \int_0^s(W_u^2+u)du$$
But what I get is:
$$\mathbb{E}(tW_t^2 \mid \mathcal{F_s})=tW_s^2 + t^2 -ts$$
$$\mathbb{E} \left( \int_0^tW_s^2ds  \mid \mathcal{F_s} \right)= \int_0^sW_u^2du +st -s^2$$
$$\mathbb{E} \left(t- \int_0^tsds  \mid \mathcal{F_s} \right) = t - t^2/2$$
Substituting:
$$\mathbb{E} \left(tW_t^2 - \int_0^t(W_s^2+s)ds  \mid \mathcal{F_s} \right) = tW_s^2 + t^2 -ts - \int_0^sW_u^2du - st + s^2 -t^2/2$$
which is does not look like needed:
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E} \left(tW_t^2- \int_0^t(W_s^2+s)ds  \mid \mathcal{F_s} \right) &= sW_s^2 - \int_0^sW_u^2du - s^2/2\\
& = tW_s^2 - \int_0^sW_u^2du+ s^2  - 2st +t^2/2
\end{align}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without your (detailed) calculations it is hard to say what you did wrong. So let's do it step by step:

It is not difficult to check that $(W_t^2-t)$ is a martingale. Therefore, we have

$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{E}(t W_t^2 \mid \mathcal{F}_s) &= t \mathbb{E}((W_t^2-t)+t) \mid \mathcal{F}_s) \\ &= t (W_s^2-s+t) = t W_s^2 + t^2-ts. \end{align*}$$

That agrees with your result for this term. Now the next one.

$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{E} \left( \int_0^t W_u^2 \, du \mid \mathcal{F}_s \right) &= \int_0^s W_u^2 \, du + \mathbb{E} \left( \int_s^t W_u^2 \, du \mid \mathcal{F}_s \right) \\ &= \int_0^s W_u^2 \, du + \mathbb{E} \left( \int_s^t ((W_u-W_s)+W_s)^2 \, du \mid \mathcal{F}_s \right) \\ &= \int_0^s W_u^2 \, du + \int_s^t \mathbb{E}((W_u-W_s)^2) \, du + 2W_s \int_s^t \underbrace{\mathbb{E}(W_u-W_s)}_{0} \, du \\ &\quad + W_s^2 (t-s) \\ &= \int_0^s W_u^2 \, du + \int_s^t (u-s) \, du + W_s^2 (t-s) \\ &= \int_0^s W_u^2 \, du + \frac{(t-s)^2}{2} + W_s^2 (t-s). \end{align*}$$

This is different from your result. The third one is again correct. Adding all up, we get

$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{E}(X_t \mid \mathcal{F}_s) &= t W_s^2 + t^2-ts  -  \left( \int_0^s W_u^2 \, du + \frac{(t-s)^2}{2} + W_s^2 (t-s) \right) - \frac{t^2}{2} \\ &= s W_s^2 - \int_0^s (W_u^2-u) \, du = X_s \end{align*}$$

Comment: I thought that we can apply expectation to $\int_s^t W_u^2 du$ with no decomposition into $(W_u-W_s),W_s$ parts as it is obvious that we are going to look at interval $[s,t]$ which is not measurable by $\mathcal{F_s}$, no? This is why I got there such a result. One more question: I have few questions almost about the same, should I extend this post, or I can ask here?

Comment: @Ievgenii Note that $W_u^2$ is not independent of $\mathcal{F}_s$. Therefore, $$\mathbb{E} \left( \int_s^t W_u^2 \, du \mid \mathcal{F}_s \right) \neq \mathbb{E} \left( \int_s^t W_u^2 \, du \right).$$ (And thanks, there very indeed several "du" missing.)

Comment: Sorry, but this is still unclear. I am afraid, I can get this mistake again in some time. Why is it not independent? We have bounds of integral that strictly say we have $u$ which is from $s$ to $t$.  Actually far before I wrote post, I was trying to interpret integral as $\sum_{i=0}^n W^2_{u_i}(u_{i+1}-u_i),$ and I thought that $\mathbb{E} (W^2_{u_i} \big\vert \mathcal{F_s})$ is just variance. If you say that because only increments are independent this will not help me much in understanding, gg. It seems to me, that I have to get used to it

Comment: @Ievgenii No, it is not. The Brownian motion has independent increments, but this does "only" mean that $W_u-W_s$ is independent of $\mathcal{F}_s$ for $u \geq s$ and **not** that $W_u$ is independent of $\mathcal{F}_s$. (Not sure how to help you understanding this. One can show explicitly that $W_u$ is not independent from $\mathcal{F}_s$, e.g. by calculating $\mathbb{E}(W_s W_u)$...but I guess that also doesn't help much in understanding.)

Comment: I have one more question. Shall I ask a new one, or add to this? It consists of 2: $$\mathbb{E}\left (  \left(\int_0^ttdW_t \right)^3 \mid \mathcal{F_s}\right).$$ How to compute this miracle? And the second one. Assume we have stochastic process: $$X_t = \frac{W_t^2-t}{W_t^2+t}dt + tdW_t$$. Is it possible to check if the process is a martingale by using martingale property? Or this is a bad idea?

Comment: @Ievgenii The second one looks raster nasty; usually I prefer checking the martingale property directly, but in this case I would go for a different reasoning. But yes, please ask a new question - otherwise this is getting a mess.